# async and await and promise in regards to catching errors

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have a question about catching user error in async and wait.

Let say I have a route that only fetches for a single user.

routes.js

```
routes.get('/getuserbyid/:id', (req, res) => {

    const id = req.params.id;

    accountController.getById(id)
        .then((result) => {
            res.json({
                confirmation: 'success',
                result: result
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.json({
                confirmation: 'failure',
                error: error
            });
        });
});
```

I have a controller that fetches the request.
accountController.js

```
export const getById = async (id) => {

        try {
            const user = await users.findOne({ where: {
                    id: id
                }});

            if (user === null) {
                return 'User does not exist';
            }
            return user;
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
}
```

So no matter what happens either I get a null or a single record. It is still a success. 
In promises, I can reject null, so it will show up in the catch block in the route. Now that with async and await. How can I achieve the same making the null in the error block?

```
export const getById = (id) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        users.findOne({ where: {
            id: id
        }})
            .then((result) => {

                if (result === null) {
                    reject('User does not exit');
                }
                resolve(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });

}
```

Comment: You would `throw null;`

Comment: I can see a couple problems here. First, the strict test `(user === null)` is likely missing some error cases, for example `undefined`. Secondly, the try/catch is unnecessary and can go away. If `user` is anything besides a valid user object, simply throw an error right then and there. It will be handled by your `.catch()` callback above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, avoid the Promise antipattern. You have a function that returns a Promise, no need to wrap that in a `new Promise()`.

Then your funciton could look like this:

```
export const getById = (id) => {
  return users.findOne({ where: { id } })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user === null)
        throw 'User does not exit';

      return user;
    });
}
```

and the async/await version of this is

```
export const getById = async (id) => {
  const user = await users.findOne({ where: { id } });

  if(user === null)
    throw 'User does not exist';

  return user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

An `async` function always returns a `Promise`.

Using the `throw` construct within an `async` function rejects the `Promise` that is returned.

Consider

```js
function getValue() {
  return Promise.reject(null);
}

getValue().catch(e => {
  console.log('An raised by `getValue` was caught by a using the `.catch` method');
  console.log(e);
});


(async function main() {
  try {
    await getValue();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('An raised by `getValue` was caught by a catch block');
    console.log(e);
  }
}());
```

```js
async function getValue() {
  throw null;
}

getValue().catch(e => {
  console.log('An raised by `getValue` was caught by a using the `.catch` method');
  console.log(e);
}); 

(async function main() {
  try {
    await getValue();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('An raised by `getValue` was caught by a catch block');
    console.log(e);
  }
}());
```

A `try` block within an async method handles *both* synchronous *and* asynchronous errors.

Consider

```js
function throws() {
  throw Error('synchronous failure');
}


async function rejects() {
  throw Error('asynchronous failure');
}

(async function main() {
  try {
    throws();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('asynchronously handled', e.message);

  }

  try {
    await rejects();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('asynchronously handled', e.message);
  }
}());
```

A critical point to keep in mind is that asynchronous errors will not be caught if you forget to `await` the promise that rejects with them. This is the analog of forgetting to `return` inside of `.then` or a `.catch` callback

Answer (score 0):

You could just throw and exception if your value turns up empty.

```
export const getById = async (id) => {
        const user = await users.findOne({ where: {
                id: id
            }});

        if (!user) {
            throw Error('User does not exist..');
        }
        return user;        
}
```

Comment: This won't work, since you're in the middle of a try/catch and the thrown error will be caught and then returned from the async function, which isn't how promises are supposed to work. Just remove the try/catch wrapper completely and it would be much better.